# Yii2 не работает валидатор

Tags: yii2, валидация

```
['login', 'exist', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => Yii::t(app,'Этот счет уже зарегистрирован.')],
```

Все остальные работают (проверка на пустые строки, email) а вот именно проверка с БД не работает. Почему так может быть? Может что то во view в форме нужно прописать? Пробовал `required`, `'targetClass' => User::className()`, добавлять `'targetAttribute' => 'login'`. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуй написать валидатор как метод.

Comment: @fedornabilkin написал уже....просто я знаю что так должно работать, ведь этот сайт именно для этого был создан. Чтобы не опытные могли спросить у  опытных, ка быть. Понятное дело что я могу пойти "в обход" но хотелось бы решить "в лоб" данную "задачу".

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите проверить `login` на уникальность

```
['login', 'unique', 'message' => Yii::t(app,'Этот счет уже зарегистрирован.')];
```

Comment: И чем то, что вы написали отличается от моего. Словом `unique`? С чего вы взяли, что если не работает `exist`, то `unique` обязательно заработает? P s так я пробовал и не работает.

Comment: А не работает потому что идет обращение к модели. Так вот, вопрос в том, почему это обращение не работает.

Comment: Для начала укажите в вопросе где вы прописываете это правило, в отдельной моделе-форме или в сущности. 
Есть ли  в таблице user(или users) столбец login?
Попробуйте так же указать вместо `\app\models\User` - `User::class`